# Magento change shipping price on the fly SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Hi I am trying to change shipping price on the fly with the following code but it crash when the rate try to save it:

```
$shippingprice = 20.00;
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$address->setShippingAmount($shippingprice);
$address->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingprice);
$rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
         ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
$address->setCollectShippingRates(false);
$address->save();
foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
    foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
        $rate->setPrice($shippingprice);
        $rate->save();//Right here it crash 
    }
}
```

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`, CONSTRAINT `FK_B1F177EFB73D3EDF5322BA64AC48D150` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_quote_address` (`address_id`) ), query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `carrier`, `carrier_title`, `code`, `method`, `method_description`, `price`, `method_title`) VALUES ('2015-11-12 18:22:52', '2015-11-12 18:22:52', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Any Idea of this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from the message that you are trying to insert a shipping rate row for a non-existent address. Add some debugging info to dump out the values you are inserting and hopefully that will make the problem obvious.

Comment: I suppose that I am saving the address from this line $address->save();

Comment: Yes, but are the rate records you are inserting properly referencing the address you have just saved?

Comment: I just added $quote->save();  after addData. Thanks